# HTML form calculation - JS or PHP? (multiple variables)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, sum

I am building sort of a quiz. Example HTML:

```
<div class="panel qContainer">
    <ol id="left">
        <li>
            Question1:<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="1A" name="SortingQ1" />1A
            <input type="radio" value="1B" name="SortingQ1" />1B
            <input type="radio" value="1C" name="SortingQ1" />1C
        </li>
        <li>
            Question2:<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2A" name="SortingQ2" />2A
            <input type="radio" value="2B" name="SortingQ2" />2B
            <input type="radio" value="2C" name="SortingQ2" />2C
            <input type="radio" value="2D" name="SortingQ2" />2D
            <input type="radio" value="2E" name="SortingQ2" />2E
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
</div>
```

For calculating result there are 5 variables: sL, sK, sA, sG, sB.
Each answer gives number value to these variables. Example:
1A = sL+4, sK+1, sA+2, sG+5, sB+3

With submit all values should be added up and variable with the biggest number would be returned as the result.

**My questions would be:**

- how to properly call the action of calculation/ submit values?
- how to take only the selected input values?
- how to calculate the result?

Regarding result, I think the easiest way would be with simple IF statements:

```
$x = ''; //value from input, not sure how to initialise it
if ($x == '1A'){
    $sL=+4;
    $sK=+1;
    $sA=+2;
    $sG=+5;
    $sB=+3;
}
```

Of course, I am not sure if PHP does such calculation logic. Maybe Javascript would be easier? At least to do the calculation itself. It's pretty straight forward with JS. I am considering PHP, because result will be applied to user database field.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Let me know if you have any questions.
(This form will be used in phpBB environment)

Here is a simple example of my idea:
Quiz What animal you are?

Possible results: R1 = lion; R2 = penguin;

**Question1** would be: "Do you eat meat?"

**1A - Yes** (R1=+1; R2=+0);

**1B - No** (R1=+0; R2=+1);

**Question2** would be: "Do you like cold or heat?"

**2A - Cold** (R1=+0; R2=+1);

**2B - Heat** (R1=+1; R2=+0);

After answer variables are SUMed result with higher sum is returned (lion OR penguin)

Comment: If you use JS someone can always change the calculation if they want to. Though it doesnt seem like thats a huge deal in this instance. You could do it with either JS or PHP.

Comment: Through JS it will be dynamic, i.e. there will be no need to reload the page. With PHP, you have to submit the form first, but then the calculations are done by the server (and not the client).

Comment: Hello @prodigitalson, yes you are right. Security is not the biggest issue. I am looking for most streamline way of doing this, with no unnecessary load and resource use. But I am very fresh with PHP so not sure how to do such simple things as taking such values and doing such calculations. I imagine everything would be taken into arrays (answer array, user input array), then with FOR answer array would compare with user input array and add appropriate values to result variables. Yet how to do such calculations with PHP?

Comment: Hello @Qirel , well, in this case, the result is applied to user database with having some changes depending on the result, so I don't mind page reload. It's actually a good thing. On page reload questions would be hidden and only answer available.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to use javascript:

- how to properly call the action of calculation/ submit values?

You add an event listener to the button with:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
//code here
});
```

- how to take only the selected input values?

One possibility is:

```
var question1 = document.getElementsByName('SortingQ1');
for (var i = 0; i<=question1.length; i++) {
    if (question1[i].checked) {
    //question1[i] is the answer 
        break;
    }
}
```

- how to calculate the result?

Here an example:

```js
var optionsSelected = document.getElementsByClassName('option');

var submit = document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var param = {};
  param.sL = 0;
  param.sK = 0;
  param.sA = 0;
  param.sG = 0;
  param.sB = 0;

  var calSum = {};
  calSum['1A'] = [4, 1, 2, 5, 3];
  calSum['1B'] = [3, 2, 3, 4, 2];
  calSum['1C'] = [20, 30, 40, 330, 10];
  calSum['2A'] = [1, 4, 5, 5, 0];
  calSum['2B'] = [0, 5, 6, 5, 0];
  calSum['2C'] = [5, 6, 7, 0, 0];
  calSum['2D'] = [6, 7, 8, 0, 3];
  calSum['2E'] = [70, 80, 90, 100, 30];

  var max = 0;
  var par = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < optionsSelected.length; i++) {
    if (optionsSelected[i].checked) {
      let j = 0;
      for (let key in param) {
        param[key] += calSum[optionsSelected[i].value][j];
        j++;
        if (param[key] > max) {
          max = param[key];
          par = key;
        }
      }

    }
  }

  console.log(param);
  alert("max " + max);
  alert("max param " + par);

});
```

```html
<div class="panel qContainer">
    <ol id="left">
        <li>
            Question1:<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="1A" name="SortingQ1" class="option" />1A
            <input type="radio" value="1B" name="SortingQ1" class="option"/>1B
            <input type="radio" value="1C" name="SortingQ1" class="option"/>1C
        </li>
        <li>
            Question2:<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2A" name="SortingQ2" class="option"/>2A
            <input type="radio" value="2B" name="SortingQ2" class="option"/>2B
            <input type="radio" value="2C" name="SortingQ2" class="option"/>2C
            <input type="radio" value="2D" name="SortingQ2" class="option"/>2D
            <input type="radio" value="2E" name="SortingQ2" class="option"/>2E
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples! I am a bit confused with this part: `for (var i = 0; i<=question1.length; i++) {
    if (question1[i].checked) {` IF here would do same thing for each question1 variable. SO I don't think that would work correctly, unless I misunderstood. The things is, EACH variable will add different number values to result variables. Result variable with the biggest sum will be returned as the result.

Comment: @KamiSama You do a calculation based on the response given by the user. If user pick one specific, the other options are calculated. But it depends on the implementation.

Comment: @kamiSama Run the jsfiddle, I'm guessing the calculation are 1,2 or 3 you should put your formula there.

Comment: @KamiSama in calSumQ1[A1]  you put the formula for A1, in calSumQ1[A2] the formula for A2 and so on

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. While first answer is 1A = sL+4, sK+1, sA+2, sG+5, sB+3, second answer is 1B = sL+1, sK+3, sA+4, sG+2, sB+5 You see? That's what I mean. In your example one answer has one variable. In my case, one answer has 5 variables.

Comment: @KamiSama Yes, I put one value since I don't know the variables. So You should put the other variables.

Comment: SO how would that look like? `calSumQ1['1A'] =  1, 2, 3, 4, 5;` ?

Comment: @KamaSami It depends. 1+2+3+4+5 or the formula you want.like (s1 +4)*400/m4

Comment: again, this way only one result is received. In my case, 1 answer has 5 separate values added to 5 separate variables. Maybe this will make more sense to you: `var 1A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; var 1B = [2, 4, 5, 3, 1];`. So I guess, what I need is array within an array?

Comment: @KamiSama Here you have an example https://jsfiddle.net/hLbrd7q2/ but i'm inventing the values. In calSumQ1['1A'] ,  calSumQ1['12'] could do what you want.

Comment: Okey, we're getting there. Now the sum calculation is in the wrong place too. The result should be: `sL= sL+1A[sL value]+2B[sL value]` Basically we add sL values from each answer and that is our result. NOT the total sum of answer variables.

Comment: yes, exactly that! Tho your method seams a bit too detailed/ complex, than I would like. I will try to simplify it. Thank you for the general idea! I'll make use of it

Comment: @KamiSama yes, of course.it is quite complex. It could be solved with one for. And the formulas.. it depends on the complexity,  but maybe could be more simple.

Comment: @KamiSama I've updated the answer with a relatively simple code.

Answer (score 0):

> how to properly call the action of calculation/ submit values?

A `form` will help immensely to deal with the data server side. So I'm assuming you want to calculate upon `submit`.

[This MDN documentation describes sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data). You'll see how to view the `request` object via tools and programmatically access it server side.

---

> how to take only the selected input values?

That's taken care of in the above.

---

> how to calculate the result? ... Example: 1A = sL+4, sK+1, sA+2, sG+5, sB+3

The example makes no sense to me. Descriptive variable names might help.

#### Questions and Answers as data structure. Think about it for now, don't go rewriting everything!

All this can go away if the questions/answers were in an array, let's say. Then just look up the answer.

I will assert as a universal truth that data structures simplify all your code everywhere. It is easily used both client side and server side. I have no doubt it can help fix this incomprehensible calculation. A structure is a consistent "form" that will help get data from the UI page to the database, back and forth. It gets rid of lots of lose variables all over the place. It reduces redundant variables. Functions are simpler when using data structures.

What might it look like? Use arrays, objects, etc. to group things that belong together. There is no "right" answer. Often there is a nesting of structure reflecting the relationship of the objects. Sometimes things are structured (grouped) because they interact.

```js
var aQuestion = { 
   question : "question one",
   answers : [ 'ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3'],
   correct : 0    // index into answers array
   };

var twentyQuestions = [
   { 
   question : "question one",
   answers : [ 'ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3'],
   correct : 0    // index into answers array
   },

   { 
   question : "question two",
   answers : [ 'ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3'],
   correct : 2    // index into answers array
   }

   // ... and so on.
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples! I was thinking about using FORM before, but was not sure if that's the best way. Now, going to my structure. Imagine it this way: result is chosen from 5 variables (R1, R2, R3, R4, R5). Each question has one available answer. One answer ADDs value to EACH result variable hence: `1A = R1+4, R2+1, R3+2, R4+5, R5+3` That is what 1 questions answer A will add to result variables. Answer B would add these values: `1B = R1+1, R2+3, R3+4, R4+2, R5+5` . Let me know if that makes more sense now. Result variable with the biggest sum is the end result.

Comment: So there are 5 "categories" and each question, answered correctly, adds a given amount to each category, yes?  Then each question has different amounts? Save these in a structure and look them up too! But what does R1, R2, etc. mean? how about meaningful variable names? That will help our understanding.

Comment: Well, there is no "correct" answer. You can compare this to those online quizzes like "What super hero you are? , What animal you are? ,...". Making a very simple example: **What animal you are?**. Possible results: R1 = lion; R2 = penguin;  

**Question1** would be: "Do you eat meat?"
**1A - Yes** (R1=+1; R2=+0);
**1B - No** (R1=+0; R2=+1);

**Question2** would be: "Do you like cold or heat?"
**2A - Cold** (R1=+0; R2=+1);
**2B - Heat** (R1=+1; R2=+0);

Let me know if now it makes more sense,

Comment: Hmm. So you're not asking "what animal are you?" You're asking indirect questions like "do you eat meat?" to determine what the animal is. So each  indirect questions' answers are weighted? I'm trying to see how all this can be abstracted - an array of results for example - so general functions can be written that simply iterate the structure (array(s)); thus functions are fewer, simpler, shorter, reusable.

Comment: .... If I'm correct, above, then I'd say to be consistent all questions have 5 variables (or whatever that maximum number is). In the case of  "Do you eat meat?" It's only 2 that matter (yes/no), so variables 3 through 5 get +0. The point is to create the concepts - abstractions -to look the same, behave the same, so that everything is handled the same. Thus code will stay simple and not get out of control as [@Emeeus comment rightly states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160840/html-form-calculation-js-or-php-multiple-variables/51161968?noredirect=1#comment89310917_51161311)

Comment: P.S. [@Emeeus jsFiddle example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160840/html-form-calculation-js-or-php-multiple-variables/51161968?noredirect=1#comment89309883_51161311) is getting to what I'm talking about. The variables seem to have the same names in the same order so I suspect the `calSumQ1, calSumQ2` etc. can be reduced to a single function.

Comment: @radarbob I've updated my answer, I think the simplest concept of the problem is  weighting (I don't know if the word is right. ponderación is in my language). There is no correct answer, so the complexity is how to weight each variable in each interaction.

Comment: @radarbob another example for you, in case you misunderstood. (continuing previous example topic of What Animal you are): **Question3** would be: "Do you have two eyes?" **1A - Yes** (R1=+1; R2=+1); **1B - No** (R1=+0; R2=+0); **1C - Come and find out** (R1=+1; R2=+0); SO idea is that each answer has SAME amount of variable data, but it is always different (not only 1 or 0. It would go from 1 to 5, for total 5 variables). And each question can have different amount of available answers